# Getting Values of other Series through tooltip

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0, mschart

I'm having a Chart whose data is coming from a list.

This class has id and count1 and count2 as Properties...

Now, i have a list of class...where the values are...

```
Id Count1 Count2

1    -10    20

2    -15    15
```

Now,
i do a simple bind...with multiple series

```
Chart1.DataSource = ListObjOfThatClass
Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Id";
Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Count1";
Chart1.Series[1].YValueMembers = "Count2";
Chart1.DataBind();
```

Now, everthing works fine..

My Que: When i hover over the DataSeries, i show a tooltip for that particular YValueMember as "#VALY";

```
Chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "#VALY";
```

Is there any way that I can show the value present in the other series?
i.e

`Count2` value, of the `series[1].YValueMember` which I initialized earlier...??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way is too create your own DataPoint for the series, and not use the datasource. Then you can put whatever you want in the tooltip:

```
foreach (var o in ListObjOfThatClass)
{
    var p1 = new DataPoint();
    p1.SetValueXY(o.Id, o.Count1);
    p1.ToolTip = string.Format("{0}", o.Count2);
    Chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(p1);

    var p2 = new DataPoint();
    p2.SetValueXY(o.Id, o.Count2);
    Chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(p2);
}
```

Comment: the id is a string property and the Count columns are decimal..??? will de query work..??

Comment: The previous code didn't work for string value. I updated the code, and it work with Id as string.

Comment: hey, is it possible for me have the label on the right side of the generated series.!!?? as of now, i'm getting the label on both sides of the series..!!

Comment: Post a new question with your new problem!